# Typing effect for javascript creating new line before typing next span item

Tags: javascript, css, html

This part of my java script created a style element that acts like a type writer css effect on my website. For some reason when it changes the span item, the style element goes to the new line before typing again on the original line. See image.

[image]

html

```
<h1>Hi, Im Roshni. My skills include
<span
 class="txt-rotate"
 data-period="2000"
 data-rotate='["T-SQL.", "HTML5.", "CSS.", "C#.", "SSRS & SQL-RD.", "Sharepoint Designer.", "Java.", "MySQL."]'></span>
</h1>
```

javascript:

```
  // INJECT CSS
  var css = document.createElement("style");
  css.type = "text/css";
  css.innerHTML += ".txt-rotate > .wrap { border-right: 0.08em solid #666 }";
  document.body.appendChild(css);
};
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle so that we can reproduce your problem?

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BZxzrv

Comment: Added a code pen above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
span {
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 1px 5px 3px 0px;
}
```

seems to work.